# Putting plots and graphs on a word document

Tags: plotting, export

Is there a way to copy and paste or save an image of a graph into a word document?

Comment: Uh... Right-click on plot in MMA -> Copy Graphic, then paste in appropriate application? We will need A LOT more details if you want a better answer.

Comment: This question is not a simple as it sounds as.  All the graphics formats available seem to have some disadvantages: PNG is a bit map so vectors and text may be degraded at some resolutions (other bit map formats are probably worse);  EMF is windows specific and seems highly unreliable if moved to a computer that doesn't have the correct fonts installed; PS can look horrible (or not appear at all) in the word document, but can be very effective when converted to PDF; PDF is not necessarily well supported.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(10549)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10549), [(54708)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54708).  Related (maybe duplicates): [(34984)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34984), [(38715)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38715), [(69322)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69322)

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
Export["filename.png", yourgraph]
```

Where `"filename.png"` `filename` is the name you want to give your file `.png` is file format and `yourgraph` is your `Graph` or `Plot`

Alternatively, as @MarcoB has indicated you can do right-click on the plot and choose Save-as option to save your `Plot` or `Graph` as an image file.